# The error is inn the firebaseRecyclerAdapter view adapter section

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

the error message is : incompatible types: FirestoreRecyclerOptions cannot be converted to FirebaseRecyclerOptions ----
and the code is as follows.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agencies);

        firebaseFirestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //views definition
        agencyFeed = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.agencyRecyclerView);

        //------Requirements for retrieving data and storing it to recycler view---

        //Query ----- for retrieving data from firestore
        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Agencies");

        // recyclerOptions
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AgencyModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AgencyModel>()
                .setQuery(query,AgencyModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AgencyModel, AgencyViewHolder>(options){

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public AgencyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.agency_cards,parent,false);
                return new AgencyViewHolder(view);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AgencyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AgencyModel model) {

                holder.name.setText(model.getName());
                holder.location.setText(model.getLocation());

            }
        };

        agencyFeed.hasFixedSize();
        agencyFeed.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        agencyFeed.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    //viewholder class
    public class AgencyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private TextView name, location;

        public AgencyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name= itemView.findViewById(R.id.agency_name); //name of agency
            location= itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationTextView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Firestore according to your query, therefore you have to use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and not `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Therefore change:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AgencyModel, AgencyViewHolder>(options){
```

into this:

```
adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<AgencyModel, AgencyViewHolder>(options){
```